# Heroku static site not loading the page data when switching to new pages

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, heroku, static

Created simple static site on Heroku using this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby.

When I open the pages locally in my browser, everything works fine. I click on links, and I land on the pages I want.
But when I run rackup (`localhost:9292`) or push it to heroku, the homepage loads, then if I try to go to something like `page2.html`, the url loads, but the browser still shows data from the the homepage.

I recreated a simple example: https://peaceful-atoll-24169.herokuapp.com. I have an index page with `Hello` on it. It should link to a page with `Yo` on it. It goes to the page, but doesn't change the page content when you click the link.

Any idea what may be going on? I feel like it may be due to my config.ru file? Here is it's content.

```
use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly will u like to do? do you wish to create a Rails project that you can host on Heroku?
If yes there is a better an easier way to do from your local machine using a [gem](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) created by heroku. If you need more help with the steps on pushing/hosting your app on heroku, let me know.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I added an example to show you exactly. https://peaceful-atoll-24169.herokuapp.com. I just want a simple site with a page linking to another page. When you click on hello, it should go to 2.html AND change the page content to `Yo`. But instead the url changes, but the page content doesn't. Any thoughts?

Comment: my advise is for you to first create a rails app from your local machine and then hosting then push it on heroku for hosting. I will give you the full instruction on how to do this in a new answer thread.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you already have rails installed on your local machine if not you can install rails using this [link](http://installrails.com/)
 1. Create a new rails application from your terminal or command window. Use `rails new name-of-app` to create a new rails app
 2. Change directory into your name-of-app folder and ensure that the rails server runs and you are able to preview the app. Preview app by running `rails server` from the current name-of-app folder. You can stop the server from running by Command+C on MacOS or Ctrl+C on PC
 3. Initialise a git repository for your app files, run `git init` then run `git add -A` then `git commit -m "Initial commit of app"` and then `git push` (ensure you do this from the name-of-app directory)
 4. Organise your Gemfile to include this, remove sqlite from the default database to use in development environment. You can see a sample of this in my github [repo](https://github.com/mayordwells/alpha-blog/blob/master/Gemfile)

```
group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'

end
```

5. Run `bundle install`
6. Create a Welcome Controller in name-of-app/app/controllers folder
   class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
     def index

   end
   end
   Check [here](https://github.com/mayordwells/stock-portfolio/blob/master/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb)
   root route for welcome#index in config/routes.rb `root 'welcome#index'` see [here](https://github.com/mayordwells/stock-portfolio/blob/master/config/routes.rb)
7. Create a welcome folder under your app/views/ folder and within the folder create an index.html.erb file and fill it in with

   ## Welcome to my app
8. Preview your app by running `rails server` ensure that it goes to the index page.
9. Commit your code to git by repeating step 3.
10. Create an heroku app by running `heroku create` (ensure you have [heroku toolbet](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line) installed on your local machine and login by using `heroku login`
11. Deploy your code project to heroku by running `git push heroku master`
    TIP: To change the name of your application run `heroku rename newnameofyourapp`

I hope this helps.